# Add VueJs modal component to Laravel template

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Question about simple situation,  I want add vue [modal component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/modal.html) to default Laravel project.
When I registered in this way :

```
Vue.component('modal', {
  template: '#modal-template'
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    showModal: false
  }
})
```

And named component like this :

```
ModalComponent.vue
```

Browser give me next errors.
[image]
All details in the [Github repository](https://github.com/Dos4dev/ModalComponent/blob/master/resources/js/app.js)

By the way, maybe better add modal window from bootstrap with jQuery or it will be messy?

Comment: did you try out my answer

Comment: Your answer awesome, but I got error https://i.imgur.com/Glhtf6x.png After simple google, I added parameter default and it help.  Now it's like this: Vue.component('modal', require('./components/ModalComponent.vue').default); thank you a lot

Comment: sorry that error is fired since i missed in the component file to add the `script` section and `export default{}` inside it, i edited my answer by adding that and you don't need `.default`

Comment: Awesome, this error helps me better understand Vue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should have :

```
   Vue.component('modal', require('./components/ModalComponent.vue'));
```

and inside your `ModalComponent.vue` file:

```
<template>
<transition name="modal">
    <div class="modal-mask">
      <div class="modal-wrapper">
        <div class="modal-container">

          <div class="modal-header">
            <slot name="header">
              default header
            </slot>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-body">
            <slot name="body">
              default body
            </slot>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-footer">
            <slot name="footer">
              default footer
              <button class="modal-default-button" @click="$emit('close')">
                OK
              </button>
            </slot>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </transition>
</template>
<script>
  export default {

  }
</script>
```

**view.blade.php**

```
<div id="app">
  <button id="show-modal" @click="showModal = true">Show Modal</button>
  <!-- use the modal component, pass in the prop -->
  <modal v-if="showModal" @close="showModal = false">
    <!--
      you can use custom content here to overwrite
      default content
    -->
    <h3 slot="header">custom header</h3>
  </modal>
</div>
```